# BinarySearchTree iterator

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

**BSTIterator class:**

```
public class BSTIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>, Iterable<E> {

protected E rootData;
protected int size;
protected int counter;
protected TraversalType traversalType;
protected LLQ<E> traversalQueue;

public BSTIterator(E rootData, int size) {
    this.rootData = rootData;
    this.size = size;
    this.counter = 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    return counter < size;
}

@Override
public E next() {
    counter++;
    return traversalQueue.dequeue();
}

@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return this;
}

public void setTraversalType(TraversalType traversalType, LLQ<E> traversalQueue) {
    this.traversalType = traversalType;
    this.traversalQueue = traversalQueue;
}
```

}

**Method in BinarySearchTree Class:**

```
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    if (root == null) {
        return new BSTIterator<>(null, 0);
    } else {
        switch (traversalType) {
            case INORDER:
                return new BSTIterator<>(root.getData(), size, inOrderQ);
            case PREORDER:
                return new BSTIterator<>(root.getData(), size, preOrderQ);
            case POSTORDER:
                return new BSTIterator<>(root.getData(), size, postOrderQ);
            default:
                 return new BSTIterator<>(null, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a method that supports enhanced for loop traversal for binary search tree. I am getting an error when instantiating a new BSTIterator object that states cannot infer type arguments.

Comment: What's `BinarySearchTree.root`?

Comment: And what *should* the type parameter be for `BSTIterator<>(null, 0)`?

Comment: the root is the first element in a perfect balanced binary tree... essentially the median of the key values. The type parameter for BSTIterator<>(null,0) is when the root is null and therefore there is no tree to traverse.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I forgot to mention your name in the above post. Thank you

Comment: Weirdly, you use `<T>` on this method and `<E>` on the other class.  Is that an issue?  Also should we assume that you want the return type of `iterator()` to match this definition: `public Iterator<E> iterator() `?

Comment: Hmm: `BSTIterator class:  public class BSTIterator<E>` So BSTIterator is a top level class, not a nested class inside of BinarySearchTree.  I haven't tested this idea, but I wonder if there's no way for the `iterator()` method to connect the `<E>` and the `<T>` to be the same variable...

Comment: I wasn't asking what `root` *models*.  I meant what is its *type*?  What is the return type of its `getData()` method?  What *is* it?